# About the Rails route namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In my Rails app,I have a controller `/app/api/mem_controller.rb`

```
class MemController < AplicationApiController
  before_filter :mem_login?
  def follows
    _mem = MemAccount.find(params[:id])
    render json: {
      :items=> _mem.follow_mems.limit(page_size).offset(page * page_size),
      :count=> _mem.follow_mems.length
    }.as_json(:methods=>['avatar_url'])
  end
end
```

I add a config in `application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'api', '*')]
```

My route is:

```
namespace :api do 
  get "mem/:id/follows" => 'mem#follows'
end
```

Now I want the route is `/api/mem/1/follows`.

But this raise error:

```
uninitialized constant Api
```

If I  take out the `namespace` wrapper,`/mem/1/follows` will do work.

Then I want to know how can I realize `/api/mem/1/follows` throuth the route keywords `namespace`,I need the `api` prefix to avoid the conflict.

I don't want to place the `api` folder under `/app/controller/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes sure, because you are using namespace.
try this:

```
class Api::MemController < AplicationApiController
    ...
end
```

and that controller MemController should be:

```
app/controllers/api/mem_controller.rb
```

if you don't want to create sub-folder, then you should use `scope` instead of `namespace` in `routes.rb`, and in that case you can keep your `MemController` without changing (I mean you don't need to add `Api::`)

```
scope '/api' do

end
```

more explanation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Yes,this will work!But I  don't want to place the `api` folder under `/app/controller/` ,I just want to independent the `api` from `controller`.any other solution?thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer, if you don't want to use `api` folder, then use `scope`.